# Mongodb C++ API insert binary (images)

Tags: c++, mongodb, opencv, mongo-cxx-driver

I looked around and couldn't find a working example for mongocxx binary insert.

I want to insert images to the MongoDB through mongocxx. I can insert except binary.

I am seeking a working example for binary (image) insert to MongoDB through mongocxx. I am using OpenCV.

Comment: I'll show you mine if you show me yours - well, maybe.  The point is have a go and then ask a specific problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you've manage to store your image in a buffer (for instance in `std::vector`), you need to use

```
bsoncxx::types::b_binary img {bsoncxx::binary_sub_type::k_binary, 
                              uint32_t(raw.size()),
                              raw.data()};`
```

Then you can pass the `img` object via the common `document{} << ...` syntax.

Comment: Hi Frédéric Samier,

How I can insert same image as base64 ? any quick way?

Comment: Awesome tip, [here's](https://gist.github.com/Sphinxs/aba7d2b0ba0c1ff2fffb6baa76ad3797) my complete implementation.

Comment: To download, [here's](https://gist.github.com/Sphinxs/c7d08eb5efa8219be65505b9d0fd2811) the implementation